# Django: base model signal handler doesn't fire

Tags: python, django, signals

In the following sample code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

# Create your models here.
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        print "Parent save..."
        super(Parent, self).save(**kwargs)

def pre_save_parent(**kwargs):
    print "pre_save_parent"
pre_save.connect(pre_save_parent, Parent)

class Child(Parent):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        print "Child save..."
        super(Child, self).save(**kwargs)

def pre_save_child(**kwargs):
    print "pre_save_child"
pre_save.connect(pre_save_child, Child)
```

`pre_save_parent` doesn't fire when I a Child is created:

```
child = models.Child.objects.create(color="red")
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an open ticket about this, [#9318](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9318).

Your workaround looks fine. Here are two others suggested on the ticket by [benbest86](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9318#comment:6) and [alexr](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9318#comment:7) respectively.

1. Listen on the child class signal, and send the Parent signal there.

   ```
   def call_parent_pre_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
       pre_save.send(sender=Parent, instance=Parent.objects.get(id=instance.id), created=created, **kwargs)
   pre_save.connect(call_parent_pre_save, sender=Child)
   ```
2. Do not specify the sender when connecting the signal, then check for subclasses of parent.

   ```
   def pre_save_parent(sender, **kwargs):
       if not isinstance(instance, Parent):
           return
       #do normal signal stuff here
       print "pre_save_parent"

   pre_save.connect(pre_save_parent)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the information Alasdair. I hadn't thought of #1 but the  `get` turns me off that. I prefer my `hasattr` to the `isinstance` approach.

Comment: I prefer the `hasattr` and `isinstance` methods to #1 as well. #2 has the advantage that you can connect multiple receivers to the `pre_save` signal. However, if it's your app, that's not so important, as you can always add more functionality to the `Parent.pre_save` method.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realise `sender` was an optional parameter to `connect`. I can do the following:

```
def pre_save_handler(**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if hasattr(instance, 'pre_save'):
        instance.pre_save()
pre_save.connect(pre_save_handler)
```

This allows me to write per Model `pre_save` methods, and they in turn can call any base class versions (if they exists).

Any better solutions?